One Click LAMP install on Google Cloud Platform gives MySQL error when trying to access Admin
I'm trying to install a LAMP stack on Google Cloud Platform in a VM Instance. I chose the Googele One Click LAMP deployment. After installing when I click on Admin I get this error: The mysqli extension is missing. Any advice? I would think they would have bullet proofed this?
I tried editing the php.ini and it's empty. I was expecting to be able to access the myPHPAdmin.

Try this question on PHP Admin.

I had the same problem, which i couldnt resolve.
Ended up installing lamp manually :)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I just ran into this same problem.  It seems like there's a disparity between the version of PHP that the server thinks it has versus what is actually being used by phpmyadmin (and other code files you might add)
When I do php -v in SSH I am told I'm running PHP 8.3.12
But when I add a phpinfo() file it says it's running 8.1.28
So these Unix commands fixed it for my actual PHP 8.1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php8.1-mysqli
sudo systemctl restart apache2

If that doesn't fix it for you, perhaps try checking what version of PHP your Apache is actually using by creating a phpinfo.php file that just contains:
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

And then perhaps update the Unix commands above to have the version number you're seeing from running that page.
